# Calendar issue in Adding month +1 to to calendar month in Android

Tags: java, android, date

I am using the following code

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println("Before "+cal.getTime());
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 01);
System.out.println("After "+cal.getTime());
```

the output is

```
Before Thu Jan 31 10:07:34 IST 2013
After Sun Mar 03 10:07:34 IST 2013
```

for adding `+1` to **jan** is giving **mar** month. may be it returning correct output if we add 30 days to present date. but i want to show **feb** month. can any body help me please..

Answer (score 62, accepted):

you can see the +1 to set field is adding 30 days date different to your dates(observed from your output.)

if you want months then use the code

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println("Before "+cal.getTime());  //Before Thu Jan 31 10:16:23 IST 2013

cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
System.out.println("After "+cal.getTime()); //After Thu Feb 28 10:16:23 IST 2013
```

Comment: the Calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1) doesn't add 30 days, it add exactly 1 month.
`Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyy");
  cal.setTime(df.parse("20-FEB-2015"));
  System.out.println("Before "+cal.getTime()); //Before Fri Feb 20 00:00:00 EET 2015

  cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
  System.out.println("After "+cal.getTime()); //After Fri Mar 20 00:00:00 EET 2015` I am using JDK 7

Comment: Its not 30 days. it can be 29, 30 or 31.

Answer (score 7):

You have to use `add()` like,

```
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
```

OUTPUT ->

```
Before Thu Jan 31 10:15:04 IST 2013
After Thu Feb 28 10:15:04 IST 2013
```

Answer (score 2):

This kind of date-time work is easier using either:

- [**Joda-Time**](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 library

  - Popular replacement for the java.util.Date & .Calendar classes bundled with Java
  - Open source
  - Free of cost
  - Actively maintained (as of 2014-02)
- [**java.time** package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)

  - New in [Java 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8)
  - Inspired by Joda-Time, but re-architected
  - Defined by [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310)
  - [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) available

## Example Code

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" ); // Or, DateTimeZone.UTC
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( timeZone );
DateTime monthAgo = dateTime.plusMonths( -1 ); // Smartly handles various month lengths, leap year, and so on.
DateTime monthLater = dateTime.plusMonths( 1 );
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "dateTime: " + dateTime );
System.out.println( "monthAgo: " + monthAgo );
System.out.println( "monthAgo start of day: " + monthAgo.withTimeAtStartOfDay() );
System.out.println( "monthLater: " + monthLater );
```

When run…

```
dateTime: 2014-02-24T01:53:22.386+01:00
monthAgo: 2014-01-24T01:53:22.386+01:00
monthAgo start of day: 2014-01-24T00:00:00.000+01:00
monthLater: 2014-03-24T01:53:22.386+01:00
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, cal.get( Calendar.MONTH ) + 1 );
```

The reason it shows `Mar 3` anyway, is because it apparently adds 30 days, which is `Feb 31st` which does not exist, so it goes to `Mar 3`.

If you wanted the last day of the next month instead, you would do something like this:

```
int month = cal.get( Calendar.MONTH );
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
if( cal.get( month ) > month + 1 ) {
    cal.set( Calendar.MONTH, month + 1 );
    cal.set( Calendar.DAY, /* here comes your day amount finding algorithm */ );
}
```

Comment: This would have the same effect. `0 + 1 = 1`, which is what the OP already passes to `set()`.